# lodash unique based on everything except attribute

Tags: javascript, lodash, unique

This is the opposite requirement to [lodash unique based on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790019/lodash-unique-based-on-attribute), here I want to make the array unique by ignoring one (or more) attribute.

So in the below, I don't care about the 'age' attribute (maybe there's multiple records, and I want to only keep where the details change).

```js
const arr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jen",
  "age": 31,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown",
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jen",
  "age": 32,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Jules",
  "age": 31,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown"
}, {
  "id": 2 "name": "Brian",
  "age": 40,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown"
}];

const unique = _.uniqBy(arr, 'id');

console.log(unique);

// const uniqueNot = _.uniqExcept(arr, 'age');
// keeps one of the Jen objects, but both of the Jules/Brian objects
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

I want the above, as the comment says, to keep one of the Jen objects, but both of the Jules/Brian objects.

I think I can do this like so:

```js
const arr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jen",
  "age": 31,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown",
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jen",
  "age": 32,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Jules",
  "age": 31,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Brian",
  "age": 40,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown"
}];

const omissionComparator = (withoutKeys) => (a, b) => _.isEqual(_.omit(a, withoutKeys), _.omit(b, withoutKeys))

const  uniqueWithoutAge = _.uniqWith(_.orderBy(arr, ['id','age'], ['asc', 'desc']), omissionComparator('age'));

console.log(uniqueWithoutAge);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

But is there a way of doing this without a custom comparator and/or having to sort the array first?

Comment: Unclear to me why you are sorting as part of this operation.  The results are the same, afaict. The `orderBy` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @kaliatech unsorted Jen with age 31 is preserved, sorted Jen with age 32 is preserved. Also, sorting by ID preserves the original order (won't necessarily always be true though)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? uniqBy + omit + JSON.stringify

```js
const arr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jen",
  "age": 31,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown",
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jen",
  "age": 32,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Jules",
  "age": 31,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Brian",
  "age": 40,
  "eyecolor": "blue",
  "hair": "brown"
}];

const keysToIgore = ['age'];

const result = _.uniqBy(arr, o => JSON.stringify(_.omit(o, keysToIgore)));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```